# Equal Height on containers but with Display Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

my problem: i have 3 containers with flex box but i wan't if i add some text in one of them, it is more height but other container more height to.
My code:

```css
.teaminfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 1em;
  height: 400px;
}

.teaminfo-div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.teaminfo-div:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaminfo">
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p style="font-size: 1.5em; padding: 0 1em 0 1em;">Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCnIj.png)

Comment: Why do you have `align-self: baseline` on the second element?

Comment: this not the way flex-works, or each child is side by side filling up entire row's height, or it shrinks to its content and is being aligned via  margin or flex rules. both behavior do not mix. you could fake your layout using transform or relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fake your layout from flex, you'll need either position or transform and not align flex properties.

possible compromise.

```css
.teaminfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 300px;/* maybe wiserr than just height */
  padding-top:120px;/* whatever, depends on how much difference you want*/
}

.teaminfo-div {
  /*display: table-cell; really needed ? */
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  /*overflow: hidden; really needed ? */
}

.teaminfo-div:nth-child(2) {
  position:relative;/* or use transform */
  top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaminfo">
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
  <div class="teaminfo-div">
    <h2>Baguette</h2>
    <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p style="font-size: 1.5em; padding: 0 1em 0 1em;">Your contribution what you do lol</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css and always Write less code for better performance

```
.teaminfo
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.teaminfo-div
{   display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 25%;
}

.teaminfo-div:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox properly: Basically all of you have to do for equal height flex-children is set display: flex on the parent. You set a bunch of align-self on the children and also a fixed height for the parent. Remove it all.

```css
.teaminfo
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.teaminfo-div
{
    height: auto;
    border: 2px black solid;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaminfo">
            <div class="teaminfo-div">
                <h2>Baguette</h2>
                <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
            </div>
            <div class="teaminfo-div">
                <h2>Baguette</h2>
                <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                <p>Your contribution what you do lol</p>
            </div>
            <div class="teaminfo-div">
                <h2>Baguette</h2>
                <img src="image/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px">
                <p style="font-size: 1.5em; padding: 0 1em 0 1em;">Your contribution what you do lol</p>
            </div>
        </div>
My CSS:
```